# How to pass curl result as parameter

Tags: shell-script, curl

I have a web app that simply returns an IP address. I want to pass that IP result to another batch script that fires off an application that's supposed to connect to that IP address.

Here's my test:

```
curl http://silvo.uk.to/IPReg.dll/GetIP | bash starttelem2.sh
```

For testing, starttelem2.sh only contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "THE IP IS " $1
```

However, when I call the above curl with pipe I get what appears to be the curl download progress.

How can I simply pass the result of the curl call to my bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have used positional parameter (argument) `1` (`$1`) inside the script, use command substitution to pass the IP address from `curl` as the first argument:

```
bash starttelem2.sh "$(curl -s http://silvo.uk.to/IPReg.dll/GetIP)"
```

`$(curl -s http://silvo.uk.to/IPReg.dll/GetIP)` is command substitution, which will be replaced by the standard output of the `curl` command inside.
The `-s` option causes `curl` to not show any progress info on STDERR.

Note that, you have used the shebang as `sh` but running the script as an argument to `bash`, as `bash` is a superset of `sh`, you should consider making the shebang as `bash` too, if you don't have any specific reason not to.

Comment: Thanks, however, I still get the download progress in the result:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    13  100    13    0     0      7      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--     7
THE IP IS  41.185.26.153

Comment: @HeinduPlessis Check my edits, you need `-s` option to silent `curl`.

Comment: Wow you guys are too fast! Thanks, working perfectly! I'll look into the bash / shebang business, not familiar with the terms. Thanks again.